# Проблемы с копированием в буфер обмена кириллицы из ячеек DataGridView winforms горячими клавишами

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Непонятка получилась, как-то раньше и не задумывался.
Если DataGridView содержит данные не связанные с DataSet (с ним не проверял), и данные содержат русские символы, то выделив ячейки и скопировав их в буфер обмена при помощи штатных клавиш ctrl+c (ctrl+ins), то при вставке данных в различные редакторы за место кириллицы вижу белиберду.
Если быть точнее, то как-то так:

- Копируем - видим в буфере обмена несколько типов данных (HTML, TXT и еще что-то)
- Вставляем в notepad/notepad++/wordpad (вставляется txt данные из буфера) - видим коракозябры, однако, если копировать при русской раскладке - то данные получаются корректными.
- Вставляем в MS WORD (вставляется html тип данных по умолчанию) - видим вообще непонятно что, нет, табличка конечно прорисовалась, но данные в ней почему-то стали разных шрифтов, с кубиками и иероглифами. Причем при просмотре буфера обмена - я вижу корректные данные и в тхт и в html формате, за исключением, что в html отсуствует тег кодировки данных, все буквы кодированы в win1251, как я понял.

Данные в ячейках DataGridView только текстовые, все ячейки имеют шрифт Tahoma, пробовал использовать еще Times New Roman, стандартный MS Sans Serif, и никакой реакции... 
Чую, подвох где-то в перекодировках родного для шарпа utf8 в не очень win1251. Переписывать копирование в буфер обмена из этого контрола не хочется уж очень. Верю, что можно решить как-то более проще =) 
Сейчас приходится перегонять буфер через блокнот, чтобы после вставить в ворд.

PS: почему копирование русского текста в буфер обмена зависит от текущей раскладки клавиатуры? Я не однократно сталкивался с такими программами, которые за место русского текста выдавали квадратики, вопросики и прочую лабуду, если копирование происходило не при русской раскладки клавиатуры?

Очередные спасибы за отклики.

Comment: А на какой операционной системе бежит ваша программа? И ещё, ваша программа (.exe) написана полностью на C#, или C++ с контролами на WinForms?

Comment: @vladd, от оси не зависит, глюки проявляются и на хрюшке, и на семерке и на 8 ке. Программа на c# полностью, под 3.5 фреймворк, создана в экспрессе 2008.

Comment: Хм. Странно. А если создать новое приложение и положить туда один `DataGridView` с одним элементом без всякой привязки, проблема воспроизводится?

Comment: @vladd, Да, воспроизводится. Попробуйте скопировать и вставить текст в Эксель или Ворд мелко мягких, чтобы текст вставлялся и парсился из html составляющей буфера обмена.

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/044bcacd-f797-45d7-be42-488281666a9a) описывается та же проблема, кажется, `DataGridView` содержит баг. Там предлагается временное решение — отключить встроенное копирование и копировать в буфер через code-behind.